# Soundcloud API Search Group by track php

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

Hello all I hope someone can help. I am trying to search through a group by track id using the soundcloud API, with the following call.

So I have added my track to this group and from what I can make out of the docs which aren't bad compared to some I must say. This is the code which returns the first 50 results from this group. This part works fine however when I am trying to filter it by one track using the id array I have no luck and its still returning 50 results none of which are the track I am trying to filter.

Example

```
$tracks=json_decode($client->get('groups/18886/tracks', array('id' => '123456')));
```

I have also tried search by name, title etc no joy anyone shed any light on this for me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do a GET on `tracks/:track_id/groups` to see which groups a track is in and then filter it the other way around.

Comment: cheers nick I will give it a go thanks for the info. Sorry I can't vote up yet as I haven't made enough posts.

Comment: Thanks it does work you saved me a lot of hassle didn't see that feature listed in the docs http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users however I am assuming you can mix the /tracks /groups /comments etc to make whichever combo you require.